# How to access the action parameter via HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpcontext

I want to access the `User` in parameter via **HttpContext**. Is there a way?

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Test(User user)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You mean like [HttpContext.User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @stuartd, No. What you said is like the Extention Method.

Comment: @mjwills I use `HttpContext` where I don't have access to its parameters. And in fact I only have access to `HttpContext`. I want to access that parameter's `Type` and `Value` via `HttpContext`.

Comment: Store it in `HttpContext.Items` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#httpcontextitems